# How to extract the positions of employee from raw text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have raw text like "Mr John Fullerton is Chief Executive Officer
and Managing Director of Australian Rail Track
Corporation Ltd, and was appointed to the
position in February 2011."

I easily identified name of PERSON(John Fullerton) by using Stanford NER, now i want to extract the positions(Chief Executive Officer). Stanford NER treat Chief Executive Officer as 'O', so which method should i use here?

Comment: see the answer here on the regular stack overflow site --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745949/how-can-i-use-machine-learning-to-determine-the-company-role-of-each-employee-ba/60746251#60746251

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/paper.pdf) to see how a Knowledge Base can be built. I would say the best way is to build your own Knowledge Base based on your corpus if you have enough data.

The idea (simplified) for starting is to have patterns such as "*NAME is POSITION*" by seeing some of data. Through this you find many names and positions. Then you extract new patterns from them and scan whole data again. Do it until no new pattern shows up. Then you end up with lots of is-a relations which is what you need.

For extracting positions you may need sentence segmentation. Have a look at [slide 56](http://www.wangzhongyuan.com/tutorial/ACL2016/Understanding-Short-Texts/Slides/Understanding-Short-Texts-Part-II-Explicit-Representation.pdf) onward to get an overview.

PS: If you do not have enough data, you may crawl web and get texts and try to make your lexical databases. Target websites with more probability of having such a context.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you @Kasra But i don't have enough data, and what if we text like " Sunder Pichai CEO GOOGLE"

Comment: That is easily captured through my suggested method. That is actually for "Short Text Understanding" and your example is a pretty typical example of such case. Try to use current Knowledge Bases (WordNet, Yango, DBpedia, Probase, etc) or as I suggested, crawl web and extract text.

Comment: @Jay Pratap Pandey I think this answer fits requirement very well. In my opinion, web crawling would be a better option for customized corpus to exactly match needs. You may like to accept this as an answer, unless additional help/reference is desired.